# How to compress pdf file to reduce file size using itext5?

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm using itext5 to generate html to pdf like this:

```
// step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        writer.setInitialLeading(12.5f);
        //try to reduce the size but didn't help, only 2% decreasing rate
        writer.setFullCompression()
        writer.setCompressionLevel(PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION)
        
        // step 3
        document.open();
        
        // step 4
        
        // CSS
        CSSResolver cssResolver =
                XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(false);
        
        // HTML
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        
        // Pipelines
        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);
        
        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(new FileInputStream(HTML));
        
        // step 5
        document.close();
```

However, it doesn't help reducing the pdf size while using

```
setFullCompression
```

I tried to change the font embedded/encoding properties as well, but it seems couldn't change by Function `XMLWorkerFontProvider.register()`

Is there any better way to consider in itext?

Comment: Have you analyzed what exactly in the result PDFs requires so much space?

Comment: Based on our requirements, we use HTML as the pdf content, if we have more records in the pdf, it would make larger file size. Is there any API in itext that can  degrade the documents contents such as make an image or font smaller?